# Parse text and populate associative array from two substrings per line

Tags: php, regex, associative-array, text-parsing

Given a large string of text, I want to search for the following patterns:

```
@key: value
```

So an example is:

```
some crazy text
more nonesense
@first: first-value;
yet even more non-sense
@second: second-value;
finally more non-sense
```

The output should be:

```
array("first" => "first-value", "second" => "second-value");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php


$string = 'some crazy text
more nonesense
@first: first-value;
yet even more non-sense
@second: second-value;
finally more non-sense';

preg_match_all('#@(.*?): (.*?);#is', $string, $matches);

$count = count($matches[0]);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $return[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
}

print_r($return);

?>
```

Link http://ideone.com/fki3U

> Array (
>       [first] => first-value
>       [second] => second-value )

Comment: So, the newlines are not required in the text, i.e. could be: some crazy text more nonesense @first: first-value. Sorry that was my fault.

Comment: @Justin wait... so, how are you determining when a value ends for a particular key?

Comment: Sorry, there are semicolons, my bad, I have updated the example string. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Justin Ok, I really changed it now for semi-colons.. with testing ;)

Comment: @Justin, that is no problem, just update regexp (I updated it).

Comment: @Justin did you want any characters to be available for keys? This regex fails if you do something like @sec^ond: test;  ?

Comment: @Ryan, won't fail now, but using characters outside of `\w` for keys is not recommended.

Comment: @webarto it depends on how this is being used. If it's being used as markdown, then it may be useful to have non-word chars.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in PHP 5.3:

```
    // set-up test string and final array
    $myString = "@test1: test1;@test2: test2;";
    $myArr = array();

    // do the matching
    preg_match_all('/@([^\:]+)\:([^;]+);/', $myString, $matches);

    // put elements of $matches in array here
    $actualMatches = count($matches) - 1;
    for ($i=0; $i<$actualMatches; $i++) {
        $myArr[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
    }
    print_r($myArr);
```

The reasoning behind this is this:

1. The regex is creating two capture groups. One capture group is the key, the
      other the data for that key. The capture groups are the portions of the regex
      inside left and right bananas, i.e., (...).
2. `$actualMatches` just adjusts for the fact that preg_match_all returns an
      extra element containing all matches lumped together.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/UBAK3).

Comment: not quite... `Array
(
    [@first: first-value
] => @second: second-value

    [first:] => second:
    [ first-value] =>  second-value
)`

Comment: I fixed it and tested in PHP 5.3 :)

Answer (score 0):

Match whole qualifying lines starting with `@` and ending with `;`.

Capture the substring that does not contain any colons as the first group and capture the substring between the space after the colon and the semicolon at the end of the line.

By using the any character dot in the second capture group, the substring may contain a semicolon without damaging any extracted data.

Call `array_combine()` to form key-value relationships between the two capture groups.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1SF28))

```
preg_match_all(
    '/^@([^:]+): (.+);$/m',
    $text,
    $m
);
var_export(array_combine($m[1], $m[2]));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'first' => 'first-value',
  'second' => 'second-value',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try looping the string line by line (explode and foreach) and check if the line starts with an @ (substr) if it has, explode the line by :.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what your input string looks like, you might be able to simply use [`parse_ini_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php), or make some small changes to the string then use the function.